# Mutually Exclusive Dropdowns in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have an Excel (2013) sheet with 5 cells which each have an identical dropdown (List Data Validation). This dropdown list has exactly 5 values (A, B, C, D, E) as well. Is there any way (preferably without having to get into VB) to make the cell values chosen (and ideally choosable) mutually exclusive, e.g., B C E D A would be a valid combination, B B E D A would not.

For example, if these are the five cells:

[image]

When I use "conventional" validation (using the range `A5:A9` which I named `validRange`), you see that the pulldown menu shows all five values, even though some of these values were already used.  What I would like to see is something like this:

[image]

Where the pulldown menu includes only the values that were not yet used. Can anyone help me figure out how to create a validation range that includes only "unused" cells (like the "Clean Range" in my spreadsheet below)?

Comment: I suspect it can be done using computed values for the valid range - but once you have selected a combination, you will not be able to change it since it will be "locked in". How would you like to deal with that?

Comment: With my current solution (see my own answer) and ignore empty enabled, I can delete the current content of two cells to swap their values. Showing all values (with used values visually marked in some way) and swapping them automatically would be great as well, but I fear that would be even more involved...

Comment: Why is this still getting downvotes? It was already closed as off-topic...

Comment: a closed question cannot get "new" answers, but both question and answers can continue to be edited to improve them, and they can continue to get votes. I suggest you improve the question (based on your learning, and addressing the "must demonstrate minimal understanding" boiler plate language) then flag it to be re-opened.

Comment: To be honest, I don't see how that comment applies, as 1. What is missing? I mentioned how to make dropdowns themselves. How to make them exclusive was the question... 2. It doesn't even match the close reason which is "off-topic" which indicates that it can only really be deleted...

Comment: (Which it can't since there are answers already)

Comment: I have attempted to edit the question to a point where I think it should be "beyond reproach". It might get some of those downvotes reversed.

Comment: Thank you very much. It mostly just seems to be more verbose to me, but apparently it did satisfy some people. I'll modify the lower part when I'm at home, as ideally I wanted a list which only contains the remaining options and no empty options (which I managed to do with the method described in the link I posted in my own answer)

Comment: Yes - I realized that the solution I came up with left some blanks - but it was just something quick to try to "undownvote" the question. The new range (`cleanRange`) I created contains the following array formula: `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(validRange, usedRange, 0)),validRange, "")` where `validRange` is the initial list, and `usedRange` the range where values are entered (`A2:E2` above). I realize it needs some clean up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer online at http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal03.html they create a dynamic list via a formula and name that list. Seems to work fine.

Comment: I was going to recommend something aimilar but it seems you were able to figure it out before I got to a computer to verify my solution! This looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do this w/o VB, but maybe you could get by with a cell that reports whether or not the 5 choices were different, so at least it would be clear to the user that something needed to be fixed.